# How to reduce css when two classes have some common styles?

Tags: html, css

I am not much familiar with CSS. But I am working on it for my project related work.

I came across a case where two css classes have some common data as given below:

```
.KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data
{
display: table-cell;
font-size: 18px;
padding-top: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
-webkit-column-width: 120px;
-moz-column-width: 120px;
column-width: 120px;
}

.data_right_column
{
display: table-cell;
font-size: 18px;
padding-top: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: left;
-webkit-column-width: 80px;
-moz-column-width: 80px;
column-width: 80px;
}
```

I am trying to reduce it as below:

```
.KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data.data_right_column
{
-webkit-column-width: 80px;
-moz-column-width: 80px;
column-width: 80px;    
}
```

And while specifying class name in HTML I am specifying:

```
KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data data_right_column
```

But it's not working. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here? Is there any other way to do the same thing?

Comment: Post your html code!

Comment: I'd start by making absolutely sure I didn't have typos in the class name...

Comment: If you provide jsfiddle it will be easier to understand problem.

Comment: The css looks good, so yes, the HTML is needed to determine what goes wrong. You haven't said what goes wrong exactly, by the way. "Not working" is not very descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a base class, then add additional classes for the styles that differ

For example imagine styling some buttons:

We have a base button class that sets some defaults (shared between all buttons)

```
.btn {
  padding: 10px 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow:2px 2px #444;
  border-radius:50px;
}
```

Then you can start adding the classes that differ in style

```
.btn-red {
  background: red;
  color: #fff;
}
.btn-green {
  background: green;
  color: #fff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn">Base btn</div>
<div class="btn btn-green">Green btn</div>
<div class="btn btn-red">Red btn</div>
```

Doing it this way keeps your code DRY and makes it much easier to change shared styles.

DEMO https://jsfiddle.net/zzv09a67/2/

Answer (score 3):

```
.KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data, .data_right_column {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: left;
}

.KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data {
    -webkit-column-width: 120px;
    -moz-column-width: 120px;
    column-width: 120px;
}

.data_right_column {
    -webkit-column-width: 80px;
    -moz-column-width: 80px;
    column-width: 80px;
}
```

Comment: +1 for this. Combine any shared styles into one selector, that way if you need to change anything in future you only need to modify one set of styles.

Comment: If `data_column_right` is a variation on an element of class `KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data` then this can be further minified by putting all default styles (including a column width) into the selector for `KPIDashboardContainerInertiaMatrixCell_data` and then overriding anything that changes for the variaition with a more specific selector. See [this Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samando27/zg2rtqLg/2/)

Comment: Sure I know this :-) But I think it doesn't enhance code readability for users that are not so experienced in coding